# Postgres: Update column with array, whose values are taken from lookup table

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table with columns:
`email1, email2, ... email5, domain_freqs` and a function `get_domain: get_domain(example@gmail.com) = gmail.com`,

I have a lookup table which has the frequencies of all the email domains occurring in all emails in the database:

```
word         nentry
gmail.com    130879
hotmail.com  12981
...
```

I want to update the domain_freqs column to store an array of values pulled from the lookup table.

For example, if I have a record with:

```
email1 = bob@gamil.com 
email2 = bob@hotmail.com
```

then I want to store `ARRAY[130879, 12981, NULL, NULL, NULL]` in the domain_freqs column

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This took approx 6 mins for a database of around 1m contact records. If anyone knows a more efficient way of doing this...

```
update emails e
set domain_freqs = (    
    select array_agg(nentry) as dom_freqs from (
        select * from (
            select *, unnest(ARRAY[
              get_domain(email1),
              get_domain(email2),
              get_domain(email3),
              get_domain(email4),
              get_domain(email5)
            ]) as dom from emails e
        ) sub, LATERAL (
          select nentry from lookup_table lt 
            where word = dom
        ) lat
    ) agg group by id having e.id = agg.id
);
```